# How can I Datasync two S3 buckets in different accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If you have two `S3 buckets`, you can `Datasync` easily.

However in my case, there are two `S3` one is in a account and the other is in another account.

Is it possible to make Datasync these two `S3`?

Or is there any practice for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**S3 Cross Account Replication**

> S3 Cross Account Replication refers to copying the contents of the S3
> bucket from one account to another S3 bucket in a different account.

For more detail refer below link:

*https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html*

Comment: Thank you very much, It looks simpler than i thought. great help!!